# Toggling between two buttons JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have post containers that contains two elements: Like and dislike buttons. There are multiple posts, so I have multiple post containers each containing their respective buttons. When a button is clicked, that button should toggle between classes in its own post container. However, the problem I am facing is what if a button is "liked" and we trying to click on the dislike button. How can we toggle from the "liked" state to the "disliked" state? Here's my code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eo8xfwd/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="post-container">
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up btns"></i>
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>

<div class="post-container">
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up btns"></i>
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btns {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumbs-up-clicked {
  color: blue;
}

.thumbs-down-clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fa-thumbs-up").click(function() {
    like_question(this);
  });

  $(".fa-thumbs-down").click(function() {
    dislike_question(this);
  });
});



function like_question(question) {
  question.classList.toggle("thumbs-up-clicked");
}

function dislike_question(question) {
  question.classList.toggle("thumbs-down-clicked");
}
```

If the user likes a specific post and then decides to click on the thumbs down button, how can we make it so that the thumbs up button isn't active and the thumbs down button is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `parent` of the clicked icon and remove the class form the element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fa-thumbs-up").click(function() {
    let getDown = $(this).parent().find('.fa-thumbs-down');
    if (getDown.hasClass('thumbs-down-clicked')) {
      getDown.removeClass('thumbs-down-clicked');
    }
    $(this).addClass('thumbs-up-clicked ')
  });

  $(".fa-thumbs-down").click(function() {
    let getUp = $(this).parent().find('.fa-thumbs-up');
    if (getUp.hasClass('thumbs-up-clicked')) {
      getUp.removeClass('thumbs-up-clicked');
    }
    $(this).addClass('thumbs-down-clicked ')
  });
});
```

```css
.btns {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.thumbs-up-clicked {
  color: blue;
}

.thumbs-down-clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">





<div class="post-container">

  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up btns"></i>
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>

<div class="post-container">
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up btns"></i>
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm managing the state of your post containers by moving the `thumbs-up-clicked` and `thumbs-down-clicked` classes to the parent, and then updated the `like_question` and `dislike_question` functions accordingly.

```js
$(".fa-thumbs-up").click(function() {
  like_question($(this).parent()[0]);
});

$(".fa-thumbs-down").click(function() {
  dislike_question($(this).parent()[0]);
});

function like_question(question) {
  question.classList.toggle("thumbs-up-clicked");
  question.classList.remove("thumbs-down-clicked");
}

function dislike_question(question) {
  question.classList.toggle("thumbs-down-clicked");
  question.classList.remove("thumbs-up-clicked");
}
```

```css
.btns {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbs-up-clicked .fa-thumbs-up {
  color: blue;
}

.thumbs-down-clicked .fa-thumbs-down {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-container">
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up btns"></i>
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>

<div class="post-container">
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up btns"></i>
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, what if my button's parent is a div and then the container element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the classList of the previous or next sibling based on like or dislike. To do that , you can get hold of the next or previous sibling and add / remove the class from the classList.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fa-thumbs-up").click(function() {
    like_question(this);
  });

  $(".fa-thumbs-down").click(function() {
    dislike_question(this);
  });
});



function like_question(question) {
  question.classList.add("thumbs-up-clicked");
  let nextSibling = question.nextElementSibling;
    nextSibling.classList.remove("thumbs-down-clicked");
}

function dislike_question(question) {
  question.classList.add("thumbs-down-clicked");

  let previousSibling = question.previousElementSibling;
    previousSibling.classList.remove("thumbs-up-clicked");
}
```

Solution link : http://jsfiddle.net/9eo8xfwd/25/

Answer (score 0):

```
function like_question(question) {
  question.classList.toggle("thumbs-up-clicked");
  if(question.classList.contains("thumbs-up-clicked")){
    if(question.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("thumbs-down-clicked")){
        question.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("thumbs-down-clicked");
    }
  }
}

function dislike_question(question) {
  question.classList.toggle("thumbs-down-clicked");
  if(question.classList.contains("thumbs-down-clicked")){
    if(question.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("thumbs-up-clicked")){
        question.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("thumbs-up-clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

You can check the result in below link http://jsfiddle.net/9eo8xfwd/36/

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a class example active:

```
<div class="post-container">
  <i class="far thumbs fa-thumbs-up btns active"></i>
  <i class="far thumbs fa-thumbs-down btns"></i>
</div>
```

with this class set on the element you can target it with:

```
$('.post-container .thumbs').on('click', function(){
$('.post-container .thumbs.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
})
```

this ensures that before you set the active class on the clicked element the active class is removed from anything else then control it with css to change the color accordingly but in the event that there will be multiple elements that may contain both the like and dislike button you might need to be specific on hitting the parent element instead this may somehow be the one that might work as well:

```
$('.post-container .thumbs').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.thumbs.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Like And Dislike</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<style>
    body{
        background-color: #000;
        color: gray;
    }
    .wrapper{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 10%;
        height: 10vh;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-40%,-50%);
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .active{
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="like"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up" ></i></button>
        <button class="dislike"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>
    </div>
    <script>
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
        const like = document.querySelector('.like');
        const dislike = document.querySelector('.dislike');
        like.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            like.classList.toggle('active');
            if(like.classList.contains('like')){
            if(dislike.classList.contains('dislike')){
                dislike.classList.remove('active');
            }
            }
            });
            dislike.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            dislike.classList.toggle('active');
            if(dislike.classList.contains('dislike')){
            if(like.classList.contains('like')){
            like.classList.remove('active');
            }
            }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```